# Report.aspx to ReportViewer.aspx

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We recently had a new SSRS Environment set up and the report manager URL for report is now **Reports/Pages/Report.aspx**

The previous environment was **ReportList/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx** and would accept parameters in the url, the new one does not.

How do i go about changing this to ReportViewer.aspx? or what can i do to allow for parameters to be passed through the URL.

Comment: can you please tell me which version you were using before?

Comment: Both are SSRS 2008 R2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SSRS default installation exposes the ReportServer endpoint under the same root URL as the Reports endpoint.  ReportServer allows parameters etc in the URL, whereas the Reports endpoint provides the Report Manager portal.

But the ReportServer endpoint can be customised eg to a different URL or port, or not configured at all.  To find out, run the SQL Server Reporting Services Configuration tool, connect to the SSRS server and look under Web Service URL.  If it has been configured already, that page will show the exact URL to use.

Here's all the info on changing this configuration:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630447(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: My question is more about ho to change the url from report.aspx to reportviewer.aspx and vice versa.

Comment: I'm not following - change it where?

Comment: Where do you want to change urls. i mean in application (custom) or in reportserver...

Comment: In the report server, My previous Report Manger had Reports/Pages/Report.aspx in the URL and i could pass parameters through the URL the new SSRS Environment has ReportList/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx and will not register that parameters were passed.

Comment: I think you should follow the steps I described above to find the ReportServer endpoint URL.  That will allow parameters.

Comment: ReportViewer is using post method so you are not able to replace it either you write your custom page having form and you post your data( parm values ) to server

Answer (score -2):

The url can't be changed. Nonetheless, you can pass parameters to the server in the following way:

```
http://servername/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=reportfolder/reportName&parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2
```

Comment: Have just tested adding &parameter=value at the end of the URL - it did not work. It appears the parameter is not passed to the report when done this way.